# Evaluating Tensorflow operation is very slow in a loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, montecarlo

I'm trying to learn tensorflow by coding up some simple problems: I was trying to find the value of pi using a direct sampling Monte Carlo method.

The run time is much longer than I thought it would be when using a `for loop` to do this. I've seen other posts about similar things and I've tried to follow the solutions, but I think I still must be doing something wrong.

Attached below is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

n_trials = 50000

tf.reset_default_graph()


x = tf.random_uniform(shape=(), name='x')
y = tf.random_uniform(shape=(), name='y')
r = tf.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

hit = tf.Variable(0, name='hit')

# perform the monte carlo step
is_inside = tf.cast(tf.less(r, 1), tf.int32)
hit_op = hit.assign_add(is_inside) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)

    # Make sure no new nodes are added to the graph
    sess.graph.finalize()

    start = time.time()   

    # Run monte carlo trials  -- This is very slow
    for _ in range(n_trials):
        sess.run(hit_op)

    hits = hit.eval()
    print("Pi is {}".format(4*hits/n_trials))
    print("Tensorflow operation took {:.2f} s".format((time.time()-start)))

>>> Pi is 3.15208
>>> Tensorflow operation took 8.98 s
```

In comparison, doing a `for loop` type solution in numpy is an order of magnitude faster

```
start = time.time()   
hits = [ 1 if np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.random.uniform(size=2)))) < 1 else 0 for _ in range(n_trials) ]
a = 0
for hit in hits:
    a+=hit
print("numpy operation took {:.2f} s".format((time.time()-start)))
print("Pi is {}".format(4*a/n_trials))

>>> Pi is 3.14032
>>> numpy operation took 0.75 s
```

Attached below is a plot of the difference in overall executioin times for various numbers of trials.

[image]

Please note: my question is not about "how to perform this task the fastest", I recognize there are much more effective ways of calculating Pi. I've only used this as a benchmarking tool to check the performance of tensorflow against something I'm familiar with (numpy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slow in speed has got to do with some communication overhead between Python and Tensorflow in `sess.run`, which is executed multiple times inside your loop. I would suggest using `tf.while_loop` to execute the computations within Tensorflow. That would be a better comparison over `numpy`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

n_trials = 50000

tf.reset_default_graph()

hit = tf.Variable(0, name='hit')

def body(ctr):
    x = tf.random_uniform(shape=[2], name='x')
    r = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(x))
    is_inside = tf.cond(tf.less(r,1), lambda: tf.constant(1), lambda: tf.constant(0))
    hit_op = hit.assign_add(is_inside)
    with tf.control_dependencies([hit_op]):
        return ctr + 1

def condition(ctr):
    return ctr < n_trials

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    result = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [tf.constant(0)])

    start = time.time()
    sess.run(result)

    hits = hit.eval()
    print("Pi is {}".format(4.*hits/n_trials))
    print("Tensorflow operation took {:.2f} s".format((time.time()-start)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, session.run has much overhead, and it is not designed to be used that way. Normally, having e.g. a neural net you would call a single session.run for a dozen of multiplications of big matrices, then this 0.2 ms it takes would not matter at all. 
As for your case, you wanted something like that probably. It runs 5 times faster than numpy version on my machine.

By the way, you do exactly same thing in numpy. If you used loop to reduce instead of np.sum it would be much slower.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    import time

    n_trials = 50000

    tf.reset_default_graph()

    x = tf.random_uniform(shape=(n_trials,), name='x')
    y = tf.random_uniform(shape=(), name='y')
    r = tf.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

    hit = tf.Variable(0, name='hit')

    # perform the monte carlo step
    is_inside = tf.cast(tf.less(r, 1), tf.int32)
    hit2= tf.reduce_sum(is_inside)
        #hit_op = hit.assign_add(is_inside) 

    with tf.Session() as sess:
    #    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        # Make sure no new nodes are added to the graph
        sess.graph.finalize()

        start = time.time()   

        # Run monte carlo trials  -- This is very slow
        #for _ in range(n_trials):
        sess.run(hit2)

        hits = hit2.eval()
        print("Pi is {}".format(4*hits/n_trials))
        print("Tensorflow operation took {:.2f} s".format((time.time()-start)))
```

Comment: You are right, though, using np.sum() it is not a fair comparison. I've updated my post to sum up using a for loop; however, the speed doesn't seem to be affected

Comment: Ah, yes this numpy one is wrong too, you should do this:     `mypi=np.sum(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.random.uniform( size=(2,n_trials))),axis=0)) < 1 )*4/n_trials`, it takes 100 times less time than your code. As for question I did not say that it should be. It is about tensorflow - it is designed for certain operations and not suited for the others.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but it's not fair to say this is "wrong" - I've merely used this as a benchmarking tool. Could you please expand on what you mean by the overhead in `sess.run()`. It seems at this point the graph should be finalized and compiled (for lack of better term) and operations should be very fast to carry out.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but as I noticed tensorflow starts separate instances for running the computation. Starting them, dispatching jobs, and fetching the results would be enough to give you results like this. Back to the point, tensorflow is made mostly for neural nets, and most of the time you will have little use of it doing other things. Monte Carlo like this can be easily coded from scrach in C or numpy, and it will be always faster than some framework because it's simply less code to execute.